# How to read CSV line by line and output with php

Tags: php, date, csv, line

I have a CSV file that contains four data fields:

```
date;place;time;event
```

First one is date, as you can see.

I need to read CSV line by line, compare DATE with current date and output ten lines starting from the line with current date.

I tried this code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Zagreb"); 
$today = date('Ymd');

$file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,";");

if ($line_of_text[0] >= $today) echo $line_of_text[0] . "-" . $line_of_text[1]. "-" . $line_of_text[2] . "-" . $line_of_text[3] . "<BR>";   
}

fclose($file_handle);    
?>
```

But I can't break that after 10 lines. I used **YYYYMMDD** date format in CSV and code so basically I work with numbers, not dates.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Zagreb"); 

$today = date('Ymd');

$file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");
$counter = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,";");
    if ($line_of_text[0] >= $today) {
        echo $line_of_text[0] . "-" . $line_of_text[1]. "-" 
            . $line_of_text[2] . "-" . $line_of_text[3] . "<br />";
        $counter++;
    }
    if ($counter == 10) break;
}

fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: it works, ty... it just needs:

if ($counter == 10) { break; }

Comment: right there should be `==` I must be more careful when writing from head :)

Answer (score 1):

if condition should be fixed by adding strtotime before you can compare:

```
if (strtotime($line_of_text[0]) >= strtorime($today))
```

Your corrected piece of code will be:

```
$counter = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,";");
    if (strtotime($line_of_text[0]) >= strtotime($today)) {
        echo $line_of_text[0] . "-" . $line_of_text[1]. "-" . $line_of_text[2] 
            . "-" . $line_of_text[3] . "<BR>";
        $counter++;
    }
    if ($counter == 10) break;
}
```